# Discord.js channel name renaming stopped working, Correct format but don't know why

Tags: discord.js, channel

So I created a program that allows you to have a variable that shows how many times a command has been executed, and here is what it looks like:

```
  var timesRunned = 0
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}command`)) {
            timesRunned++
            let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('Guild-ID')
            let channel = myGuild.channels.cache.get('Voice-Channel-ID')
            channel.setName('Commands Executed: ' + timesRunned)
            .catch()
    }
```

But after I run the command more than 3 Times, The voice channel does not even change no matter how many times I run the command, it just stays as "Commands Executed: 2"
Am I doing something wrong? This is in the main app javascript file. The bot itself has enough permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's the problem. It seems like you are putting the `var timesRunned = 0` in the message event. This means that every time you run a command, this number is reset to 0, which means it forever stays at 1.

If you move the variable to outside the message event, it should work fine.

I will give you another tip, because by just moving it to outside the message event, the variable will clear every time it restarts.

What you can do is get the channel each time the command is run and see how many are on the channel already, then add 1. You would end up with something like this:

```
var channel = client.channels.cache.get('someID');
var numberExecuted = parseInt(channel.name.split(':').trim());
channel.setName(`Commands Executed: ${numberExecuted + 1}`);
```

Hope this helps.